# TextView in the middle of ImageButton inside TableRow

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I still didn`t a solution how to do that in XML. I want to center a textview over a imagebutton that are on a tablerow.

This is how should be:

[image: Desired example]

My code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp">
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip" >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:src="@drawable/options_460"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:padding="0dip" >

        <ImageButton

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/a"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonsh"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="rasp"
            android:tag="a"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:id="@+id/b"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonsh"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="rasp"
            android:tag="b"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>
    </TableRow>
    ............................................
    </TableLayout>
```

Is there any way to do that? Any suggestion would be welcomed.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Where you are writting text , as I can't see the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is that there is no need to take the table view, we have the easy alternative for it, you should try like below... here you have to just set a background 9.pach in your button and take appropriate id for the related component and you will bit your task. good luck

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Middle center text" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="left upper" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="right upper" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="left bottom" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="right bottom" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you missed the first <LinearLayout> . Thank you.

Comment: thanks @SebastianCorneliuVîrlan hope it ware help you. then it should be acceptable.

Comment: Yes, thank you :) and if I want that all this layout to be at the buttom of the screen?

Comment: @SebastianCorneliuVîrlan then you have to take a Relative  layout as a parent layout and put all above code inside it. after set the align parent bottom = true of your inside main linear it'll be set as you wish.